# Laravel Meaning of Load View function

Tags: laravel-5

I want to know what is the function of `loadView` in Laravel.
Because I have a hard time viewing my `view_path`.

```
public function loadView($view_path, $params) {
    $view = View::make($view_path, $params);
    $contents = $view->render();
    return $contents;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view path is the path to the view starting from the folder resources/views/ and without the .blade.php extension.

For example if you want to load the view /var/www/html/myProject/resources/views/front/welcome.blade.php then the view path is "front/welcome".

You should probably use "view($view_path, $params)" to load your views at the end of your controllers.
As in :

```
return view("front/welcome", $params);
```

Where did you find this loadView function ?

Comment: dear @LeprechaunCode i tried to use your advise in the similar query, but i dont get the results, i need to help in similar query here, i updated my question after test your advise also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74931244/how-to-load-compact-view-in-laravel-with-data-in-url